# Ajax how to find something in array of objects via find method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In backend PHP I have this defined in loop:

```
 foreach ( $data as $res ){
$approved[ ]        = [ 'id' => $count, 'title' => "some title" ];
$count++;$title=...
)
```

and then final list is created:

```
$list[ ] = [ 'list' => 'approved', 'values' => $approved ];
return ['list' => $list ];
```

In **javascript** I am getting these results via ajax call:

```
this.myoutput = {};
    this.http.get('backend_url).then(data => {
      let result = this.helper.isJson( data.response ) || [ ];
      console.log(result);

      this.myoutput.approved   = result.list.find( item => item.list === 'approved' );

      console.log(this.myoutput.approved);

    })
```

The first `console.log(result);` gives me all data something like:

```
list: (1) […]

0: {…}
​​​
list: "approved"
​​​
values: (13) […]
​​​​
0: Object { id: "1", title: "aaa" }
​​​​
1: Object { id: "2", title: "bbb" }
​​​​
2: Object { id: "3", title: "ccc" }
​​​
```

but `console.log(this.myoutput.approved);` gives me undefined. Is something what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key that holds your array values is named `values`, not `list`. So this should work:

```
this.myoutput = {};
    this.http.get('backend_url).then(data => {
      let result = this.helper.isJson( data.response ) || [ ];
      console.log(result);

      this.myoutput.approved   = result.values.find( item => item.list === 'approved' );

      console.log(this.myoutput.approved);

    })
```

But what are you trying to find? If you check the values array, it contains `id` and `title`, not `list`? so to find one item in your array, something like:

```
this.myoutput.approved   = result.values.find( item => item.id === "3" );
```

would make more sense to me. Note that if nothing is found, the `find()` method will indeed return `undefined` as per the specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Good luck!